# How to prove a repeating decimal sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, formal-proofs

I have to show a repeating decimal sequence converges. For example I have a sequence $\{x_n\}$ where $x_n = 0.121212...1212...$

I know that this decimal equals $4/33$. I try to find information online, but everything shows up says to make it as a geomtric series and proving it as that. However I don't think that is correct since in a sense sequences and series are different.

**Any help or references for proving this type of sequence?**

Comment: All decimal sequences converge, and for the same reason.

Comment: The idea is that the repeating decimal sequence is equivalent to the partial sums of a geometric series.  So, showing that the series converges is equivalent to showing the decimal sequence converges.

Comment: Also, sequences and series are not all that different. Series are just "special" sequences (technically, every sequence may also be written as a series), where the general term is $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$

Comment: You will inevitably talk about series when you talk about decimal sequences, because they represent a series.  It's how they're defined: .324 means $3\cdot 10^{-1} + 2 \cdot 10^{-2} + 4 \cdot 10^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a geometric series, times 12:
$$
0.12 = \frac{12}{100^1},\quad 0.0012 = \frac{12}{100^2},\quad 0.000012 = \frac{12}{100^3},\quad\cdots.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_n &= \frac{12}{100^1} + \frac{12}{100^2} + \frac{12}{100^3} + \cdots\\
&= 12\bigg(\frac{1}{100^1}+\frac{1}{100^2}+\frac{1}{100^3}+\cdots\bigg) \\
& = 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{100^n}\\
&= 12 \bigg(\frac{\frac1{100}}{1 - \frac1{100}}\bigg)\\
&= \frac{12}{99}\\
&= \frac4{33}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the fact that $0.9999999\ldots=0.\overline{9}=1$, we have
$$0.\overline{1}=\frac{1}{9},\quad 0.\overline{01}=\frac{1}{99},\quad 0.\overline{001}=\frac{1}{999},\quad 0.\overline{0001}=\frac{1}{9999}$$
and so on. It follows that any number whose decimal representation is purely periodic is an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{10^k-1}$ for some $k$. In your case $0.\overline{12} = 12\cdot 0.\overline{01} = \frac{12}{99} = \frac{4}{33}.$